# How can I consolidate mapping code between different levels of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, functional-style, map

I have a list with the following structure:

```
uf = {{{<<9>>}, {<<11>>}, {<<8>>}, {<<7>>}, {<<9>>}},
{{<<6>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<11>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<12>>}, {<<7>>}, {<<10>>}}, 
{{<<3>>}, {<<9>>}, {<<5>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<17>>}, {<<16>>}, {<<6>>}}}
```

How can I consolidate the following code into a single mapping?

```
counties[#, mesoMG1] & /@ uf[[1]];
counties[#, mesoMG2] & /@ uf[[2]];
counties[#, mesoSP] & /@ uf[[3]];
```

I have tried a combination of Map's, MapThreads with Outer's, etc but I am unable to crack it. Can someone please help?
Thanks in advance,

Thad

Comment: `MapThread[Function[x, counties[x ,#2]]/@#&, {uf[[;;3]], {mesoMG1, mesoMG2, mesoSP}}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
MapThread[Function[x, counties[x, #2]] /@ #&, {uf[[;;3]], {mesoMG1, mesoMG2, mesoSP}}]
```